# Email modifying

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for windows applications forms. I started with a basic program that sends the information in the form via email. The email functions works fine, I just can't get it to appear readable on the email message. My goal is to show each label and textbox in a different line. I.e: 
Lot number: 1111
Pieces: 2
Description: xyz... etc

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail");
            mail.To.Add("sendingTo");
            mail.Subject = "subject";  
            mail.Body = toName.Text lot.Text;


            SmtpServer.Port = 587; 
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My problem is in - mail.Body. How do I create new lines with text and variable all together that would appear nicely in an email message.

Thanks!

Comment: Build string and then append as HTML in emailBody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting both "\r\n" to move to next line.

e.g.

```
mail.Body = toName.Text + "\r\n" + lot.Text + "\r\n" + pieces.Text + "\r\n" + description.Text;

"Name: ABC \r\n Lot number: 1111 \r\n Pieces: 2 \r\n Description: xyz\r\n"
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer/voting up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to create new lines? You can do this by putting `\n` in any string.

To add a variable to a string, you can simply use the `+` character, so something like:

```
bar = foooo
barr = baaaaar
foo = bar + barr
```

You would then get:

```
foooobaaaaar
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to Use 
https://www.stringtemplate.org/ [https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4]

You can have HTML templates with variables. Then use the above lib to fill your templates with your actual values.

We are using these tools effectively in our projects.

Also note that: System.Net.Mail SmtpClient is now obsolete.
Below is from MS Documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Use MailKit instead
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Hope this helps.

Cheers!